# Enable SYSTEM_VERSIONING Error - Overlapping Dates in History Table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I recently migrated my SQL 2019 database from a VM into Azure SQL.
I used the MS Data Migration tool, but unfortunately, it wouldn't migrate data from Temporal Tables.

So. I just used the tool to create the table schemas and then used SSIS to move the data.

Since my existing history table had data in it, I wanted to keep the SysStartDate and SysEndDate fields.  In order to do this, I had to disable SYSTEM_VERSIONING in my Azure SQL database as well as DROP the PERIOD on the table.

The data migration was a success so I re-created my PERIOD on the table but when I tried to enable SYSTEM_VERSIONING with a specified history table, I get the following error:

> Msg 13573, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
>   Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because history table 'xxxxxHistory'
>  contains overlapping records.

I find this odd because the existing tables were originally joined as a temporal table so I don't understand why there would be a conflict now.

```
ALTER TABLE xxx.xxx 
ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(SysStartTime, SysEndTime)    

ALTER TABLE xxx.xxx 
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=xxx.xxxHistory))
```

I expect to get a successful temporal table. Instead, I get the following error:

> Msg 13573, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
>   Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because history table 'xxxxxHistory'
>  contains overlapping records.

I ran the following query to identify the overlaps but I don't get any:

```
SELECT 
     xxxxKeyNumeric
     ,SysStartTime
     ,SysEndTime
FROM 
    xxxx.xxxxhistory o
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        xxxx.xxxxhistory o2
    WHERE 
        o2.xxxxKeyNumeric = o.xxxxKeyNumeric
        AND o2.SysStartTime <= o.SysEndTime
        AND o.SysStartTime <= o2.SysEndTime
        AND o2.xxxxPK != o.xxxxPK
)
ORDER BY 
    o.xxxxKeyNumeric, 
    o.SysStartTime
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this explanation on the [blog of a DBA](https://curiousaboutdata.com/2019/04/15/temporal-tables-list-of-errors-with-reasons/) for the error:

> There are multiple records for the same record with overlapping start and end dates. The end date for the last row in the history table should match the start date for the active record in the parent table

This happened to me after switching the historic table, touching a few rows, then trying to go back to the old historic table.

---

It happened again, and this time the table had millions of rows. I had to write a query, comparing the start date and end date of every row in the history table.

Possible causes:

1. **For every PK, the start dates and end dates of the history rows must not overlap.**  The query below will find this specific issue.
2. **the end date of the latest row in the history for that PK, has a later end date than the start date of the PK in the main table**. It is possible to modify the above query to do this
3. **in the rows with a same PK, 2 rows cover the same time interval**. If they overlap by a single millisecond, and someone requests that exact millisecond, it won't know which of the 2 versions is the correct one.

For the first issue:

```
select ant.*,post.* , DATEDIFF(day,ant.end_date,post.start_date)
from
(SELECT
      PK_column
    , start_date
    , end_date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PK_column ORDER BY end_date desc, start_date desc)    AS current
    ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PK_column ORDER BY end_date desc, start_date desc))-1 AS previous
FROM huge_table_HIST 
) ant
inner join
(SELECT
      key_column
    , start_date
    , end_date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PK_column ORDER BY end_date desc, start_date desc ) AS current
    FROM huge_table_HIST 
) post
ON ant.PK_column=post.PK_column AND ant.previous=post.current
WHERE ant.end_date > post.start_date
```

Surprisingly, it doesn't fail if:

- you have multiple rows with exactly the same start end and end date, for the same PK. SQL Server seems to consider them a single point in space, instead of an interval. They will only appear if you request the exact millisecond in which they exist.
- there are gaps between the end date of a history row, and the start end of the next one. SQL server considers that the PK just didn't exist in that time interval.

Answer (score 2):

Temporal tables depend on the temporal table's primary key values combined with the SysStartTime do determine uniqueness in the history table.

This can very easily happen if you make changes to the primary key definition.  Also, if your history table's fields corresponding to the temporal table's PK are not populated, or many / all are populated with a default value, overlaps are detected and you get that error.

Check that your PK is defined on the system versioned temporal table, then check that the corresponding values in your history table's primary key fields are correct (i.e. unique for any given PK & SysStartTime value.)

You may have to update the history table accordingly before applying the system versioning relationship again.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also occur when there are multiple records per Primary Key for any given
`GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START` or `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END` columns.

The following queries will help identify those records.

```
select ID
from dbo.HistoryTable  
group by ID, SysStartTime 
having count(*) > 1

select ID
from dbo.HistoryTable  
group by ID, SysEndTime 
having count(*) > 1
```